# Selenium test structure

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have  written a selenium test that clicks through every option on a "admin panel" page and then takes screen shots of each new page.

I now have the task to do this test on every language there is (currently 11).

How do I proceed? 
Do I create a new test class for each language.
Or do I make a loop on my existing test that loops through each URL (different URL for each language).

The test code I have works for each language.

So what is the best practice to make this happen? Appreciate all help

EDIT Using Java, TestNG and POM

Comment: Is this a test, or is it a tool to generate screenshots? Are you doing any automatic testing of the pages, or are you simply using selenium to make it possible to take screenshots?

Comment: I guess a combination of making it possible to take screenshots but also to test every link on the site

Answer (score 1):

If you've written your test in JUnit, you could use the [Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) runner to parametrize your test. 
The you could define the languages as parameter and it automatically runs the test for all languages provided.

If you're using TestNG you can parameterize your tests as well and provide the data using a `@DataProvider` annotated method, more details [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders).

Comment: I am using TestNG, I guess there is a similar option there :)

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding use existing code so If any change will come then you need less maintainability for the script to run it properly again.

Just after each language maintain the logs and screenshot description accordingly so you can trace the bugs properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using POM!? If so, then it's of course good to re-use your page objects, but then you are restricted to not locating your web elements by their link texts, which might become difficult on some sites.

If this is not a problem on the site you're testing, then go ahead an re-use your classes. If it *is* a problem, then you should consider writing a base class per web page and derive a specific class per language from each of these base classes, where all the `LinkText` and other language-specific stuff is located. If 90% of each page is language-specific, then it might of course be more sensible to omit the base classes and simply write one class per page/language combination.

Comment: Yes I am using POM. 
The downside I see with looping through all urls in one test is the run time of the test will be a lot longer and I cant choose to only run one language test.
Also, won't I be reusing my page object no matter which path I choose? 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

@RichardHansson Use a DataProvider like Gerald mentioned above. If you use a loop then 1 error on any of the tests will cause all the other tests not to run and it may be hard to pinpoint where the issue was. If you use the @DataProvider annotation then

- each scenario will run as it's own test with no dependency on the
  other
- Each test will have it's own results in testng reports
- No duplication of code

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders